# how to stop $interval when closing the modal ($uibModal)

Tags: angularjs

I've made an interval:
`$interval($scope.sendGetRequest, 1500)`
The function is sending $http.get request every 1500ms. I want to stop this interval when closing the modal, because it is still sending the request within the interval even when I'm closing the modal.

What's the event that is triggered when the modal is being closed, so I can stop the interval there?

** I'm inside the modal scope,  I want to stop the interval there before the modal is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want to stop the $interval when the $scope gets destroyed (modal closed).

This should be inside the controller of your modal:

```
  var poll = $interval($scope.sendGetRequest, 1500);
  $scope.$on('$destroy', stopPolling);

  function stopPolling() {
      $interval.cancel(poll);
  };
```

Comment: if this answer solves your problem, then it would be good practice to accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your interval definition in a variable.

```
var myInterval = $interval(function() {
  // Do something
}, 1500);
```

Then when you want to stop it, use `cancel` method of `$interval`.

`$interval.cancel(myInterval);`

**[Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval#cancel)**

Answer (score 0):

in Your Controller :

```
$scope.openDialog = function () {
    var dialogIns = function () {
        var dialogInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'modalHtmlPage.html',
            controller: 'modalController',
        });
    };
}
```

and in your modal controller:

```
var intVal = $interval(function () {
    //$http.get request
}, 1500);

$scope.closeModal = function () {
       $interval.cancel(intVal);
       $uibModalInstance.close();
    }
```

Comment: The interval is happening inside the modal, they are not share the same scope.
I want to stop the interval inside the scope of the modal, before exiting.